Why does the number of commits shown in a git log not match with the number of commits in a git rebase -i HEAD~n?
I want to perform an interactive rebase in order to squash some commits.
The way I do this is:

use git log to search for the commits I want to squash
count the number of commits from HEAD
use git rebase -i HEAD~n where n is the number of commits from HEAD

Is this the wrong method? I have been using this technique for a while and sometimes wondered why the number of commits doesn't match up.
To demonstrate, here is the output from git log --pretty=format:"%h%x09%an%x09%ad%x09%s".
130f00e me              Fri Apr 19 16:37:15 2024 +0000  commit message
c7bb70c me on github    Fri Apr 19 17:08:28 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #419 from company/MY-DEV-BRANCH
3e3f411 me              Fri Apr 19 16:07:42 2024 +0000  commit message
47e769e colleague       Fri Apr 19 17:00:26 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #418 from company/colleague -patch-28
998be63 colleague       Fri Apr 19 16:59:53 2024 +0100  commit message
7b75da8 colleague       Fri Apr 19 16:59:31 2024 +0100  commit message
c7f0da1 colleague       Fri Apr 19 15:54:59 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #417 from company/mycolleague/HIS-DEV_BRANCH
43e927d colleague       Fri Apr 19 15:54:49 2024 +0100  Merge branch 'master' into mycolleague/HIS-DEV_BRANCH
06d62f2 colleague       Fri Apr 19 14:52:50 2024 +0000  commit message
3de4d90 me on github    Fri Apr 19 15:08:37 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #414 from company/MY-DEV-BRANCH
374add4 me              Fri Apr 19 14:00:36 2024 +0000  commit message
ba4fd3b me              Fri Apr 19 14:00:07 2024 +0000  Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/master' into MY-DEV-BRANCH
aed07ae me              Fri Apr 19 13:37:31 2024 +0000  commit message
44e119d colleague       Fri Apr 19 10:09:46 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #416 from company/colleague -patch-46
da11abe colleague       Fri Apr 19 10:09:39 2024 +0100  commit message
a74b81a colleague       Fri Apr 19 10:09:18 2024 +0100  commit message
80b4003 colleague       Fri Apr 19 09:51:56 2024 +0100  Merge pull request #415 from company/mycolleague/HIS-DEV_BRANCH
0489446 colleague       Fri Apr 19 08:50:09 2024 +0000  commit message

There are 18 lines in this output. Therefore n=18.
Here is the output from git rebase -i HEAD~18.
pick 45c0d75 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick a519421 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 5bb52cc (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 51f831a (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 530a6f3 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 72c89c8 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 59052f4 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick ce9faf9 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick e399c0a (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 82f29f0 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 9c405ed (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick a1f4893 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick b974516 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 50d2394 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 020e80c (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 09addd8 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick ef65821 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick ca4f3f7 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick e1098a7 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 2275c59 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick c3614f2 (other-colleague <62242115+other-colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 0e7fa78 (other-colleague <62242115+other-colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick b7ee582 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 117178a (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 4f68792 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 821a479 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 6ea09f1 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 0936af5 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 6b43a34 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 23a1f3e (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 9e907af (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 64c08cc (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 58e0601 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 002c5e6 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 17f71cb (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick de2b3a6 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 9a2bfb0 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 94728d9 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message # empty
pick 48f1190 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 0489446 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 06d62f2 (colleague <colleague@company.com>) commit message
pick 392e9c3 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick aed07ae (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick a74b81a (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick da11abe (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 374add4 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 7b75da8 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 998be63 (colleague <131662019+colleague@users.noreply.github.com>) commit message
pick 3e3f411 (me <me@company.com>) commit message
pick 130f00e (me <me@company.com>) commit message

# Rebase d0bea91..130f00e onto d0bea91 (50 commands)

This is clearly a lot more than 18 lines. In fact, it is a total of 50 lines.
Why does this happen? What is going on here? Clearly this method of rebasing doesn't make much sense. So what should I be doing instead?

Notes: 1.) there's a chance you'll have conflicts at any of the commits named something like "Merge branch 'master' into ..." 2.) Sometimes it's helpful to have the PR history numbers in the Git history, so you can go look at a specific PR in your tool to view additional comments and discussion that isn't retained in the Git commit history. (Mentioning this in case you were planning on squashing those commits.)

@TTT I am planning on squashing them all together, yes. The reason for this it to produce a cherry-pickable commit to put on a totally different branch which has long diverged from the master. Please don't ask about this, I don't want to think about it any more than I have to

Note your question said "squash some commits". But your last comment just said "squashing them all together"? As in, you wish to squash all of that into a single commit? In that case don't use interactive rebase, instead use just one soft reset followed by a single commit, which is much faster and easier.

@TTT That's a good point but I don't think that would have worked in this context as I have multiple other merge commits coming from the master branch. Next time I need to do this I'll try it. I'm well aware this is not good practice and I would not encourage anyone to do what I am doing here... I'm forced to do so because of how our repository works.

My comment is (probably) only relevant if you are squashing something into a single commit. If you want exactly 1 commit, you can (and IMHO should) use the reset, regardless of how many merge commits you have. If you want more than 1 commit, then interactive rebase may be required.

Some of the commits in your first list (presumably, those whose commit message begins with "Merge pull request #123 from foo") appear to be merge commits. These behave a little differently upon rebasing.
From the doc

By default, a rebase will simply drop merge commits from the todo
list, and put the rebased commits into a single, linear branch. With
--rebase-merges, the rebase will instead try to preserve the branching structure within the commits that are to be rebased, by recreating the
merge commits.

That's why your second list has more commits. The merge commits are broken down into the individual original commits they bring. Use --rebase-merges to avoid this.

You have a merge commit (git merge --no-ff) somewhere along the way so you see those commits as well.


Try using different flags to view the differences
--preserve-merges
Full explanation: What exactly does git's "rebase --preserve-merges" do (and why?)
--rebase-merges

In your case you have some -no-ff merge.
This will add "extra" commit which is a parent of (2 or more) commits



Some advice about git log:

when used for viewing the history (as opposed to scripting for example) always add the --graph option:

git log --oneline --graph


if you intend to count the n value in HEAD~n, use --first-parent

git log --oneline --first-parent

Note that this will give you the n, but as said in other answers, if there are merge commits in this list, the list of commits that will be "brought along" with git rebase is larger:
git log --graph --oneline HEAD~n..HEAD

